# Bind method to another method

Tags: javascript

Object A contains an instance of Object B.

When the user clicks a div it will invoke a method and pass an argument for Object B, however we need Object B to be able to invoke a method and pass an argument on Object A as it will have to update something respective to it.

We do not want to have to pass in the instantiated Object A into the constructor of Object B.

From within Object A, I was hoping to define:

```
    this.objectB = new ObjectB();
    ObjectA.handleUserSelection += this.objectB.handleDateTimeSelection;
```

Within ObjectA the method would look like:

```
    ObjectA.prototype.handleUserSelection(data)
    {
     //do something else with the data
    }
```

So when objectB.handleDateTimeSelection is invoked from when the user clicks the div bound to it, it would also trigger the respective objectA method.

Explanation 2)

When Object B's method is invoked, I want to invoke a method on Object A but I do not want to have to pass the entire Object A reference into Object B. Object A is aware of Object B, but Object B is not aware of Object A at all.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the question or what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: If your goal is to execute some function on ObjectA after calling ObjectB.handleDateTimeSelection, then ObjectB would need a reference to the method in ObjectA.

this.objectB.handleDateTimeSelection(ObjectA.prototype.handleUserSeleection); Then inside the body of this.objectB.handleDateTimeSelection  you can call the passed in function with whatever parameters you need.

Comment: it is really unclear what the question is here.  "I was hoping to define:" isn't a question, it's a requirement.

Comment: When objectB's method is invoked I want to invoke a method on objectA as well but i dont want to have to pass the entire objectA reference in.

Comment: I guess I could do the UI binding in Object A and have it invoke Object A/B methods respectively.

Comment: You're using objects in a very weird manner. First you compose them using inheritance. Then you want two separate objects to interact. This is not what inheritance was invented to do. Are you sure you want object A's `handleUserSelection` or is what you really want is object B's `handleUserSelection`. Note that both objects have the `handleUserSelection` method. Neither object A is aware of object B nor object B is aware of object A: they are both separate objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a method as a parameter to a function.

```
// ObjectA method definition
ObjectA.prototype.someMethod(data) {
// do something with the data
}

// ObjectB method definition
ObjectB.prototype.handleDateTimeSelection(inputMethod) {
  // Do object B stuff

  // execute callback
  inputMethod(someData);
}

// Calling it
this.objectB.handleDateTimeSelection(ObjectA.prototype.someMethod);

// or something existing
this.objectB.handleDateTimeSelection(alert);
```

Comment: handleDateTimeSelection will be found to the click event on a div and will receive the element clicked. I want to send that element clicked to the Obect A method as well but object b is ignorant to object a